# Run Expressionengine hook to trigger Netlify deploy on save

Tags: ee2

I have built templates to export my EE site as a JSON API. I am trying to set up a static site generator deploying to Netlify.

What I want is to run a curl command when I create a new entry or update an old one to trigger a build and deploy by Netlify.

```
curl -X POST -d '{}' https://api.netlify.com/build_hooks/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

I am pretty familiar with PHP but zero experience with EE. What would be the best way to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to write an Extension that is fired by this extension hook:

https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/development/extension-hooks/model/channel-entry.html#before_channel_entry_saveentry-values

Extension docs:

https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/development/extensions.html

When all set up, you'll have a method in your Extension class that is called whenever you save a new entry or update an existing one. That method will look like this:

```
public function my_extension_method($entry, $values)
{
    // Here I would recommend instantiating a Curl library to perform your curl actions
}
```

Please review the docs and let us know if you get stuck, I could probably expand my example if needed.

Comment: I will give this a shot. Sounds like it will do exactly what I want. Thanks!